# WKWebView Picture in Picture

Tags: ios, webkit, wkwebview

I am trying to use Picture in Picture in the WKWebView while the user can continue to use the app.

The problem I am having is that the WKWebView is in it's own View Controller and I do not receive a notification for when the user is trying to restore the video or closes it. But I need to know when the view controller can be removed or when it needs to be presented again so i can restore the view controller again.

I am missing a NSNotification somewhere?

Comment: I use PiP in the UIWebview, but I have problem with mp3 file.After I click PiP button, mp3 file doesn't run and my app doesn't run normally.